# jquery Ui Combobox Error on Chrome / IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, combobox

For some reason the combobox button aint showing on IE or Chrome, so i end up with just a textbox. anyone figured out how to solve?

Using latest jquery/jqueryui/combobox version.

Heres my edited version of ui.combobox (specially coz original version doesnt give an id to the new element), also theres a fix for combobox size:

```
(function( $ ) {
        $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
            _create: function() {
                var self = this,
                    id = this.element.attr("id"),
                    select = this.element,
                    theWidth = select.width(),
                    selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
                    value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
                    select.hide();
                    //fix, doesnt let the element beign too short.
                    if(theWidth < 110) {
                        theWidth = 110;
                    }
                var input = $('<input id="' + id + '-combo" style="width: ' + theWidth + 'px;">')
                    //.insertAfter( select )
                    .val( value )
                    .autocomplete({
                        delay: 0,
                        minLength: 0,
                        source: function( request, response ) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                            response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                                var text = $( this ).text();
                                if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                                    return {
                                        id: this.value,
                                        label: text.replace(
                                            new RegExp(
                                                "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                                $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                                ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                            ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                        value: text,
                                        option: this
                                    };
                            }) );
                        },
                        select: function( event, ui ) {
                            ui.item.option.selected = true;
                            self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                                item: ui.item.option
                            });
                        },
                        change: function( event, ui ) {
                            if ( !ui.item ) {
                                var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                                    valid = false;
                                select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                                    if ( this.value.match( matcher ) ) {
                                        this.selected = valid = true;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                                if ( !valid ) {
                                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                    $( this ).val( "" );
                                    select.val( "" );
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );
                    var span = $('<span style="white-space: nowrap;"></span>')
                    .append(input).insertAfter( select );
                input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                    return $( "<li></li>" )
                        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                        .appendTo( ul );
                };

                $("<button id='" + id + '-combo-button' + ">&nbsp;</button>")
                    .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                    .attr( "title", "Mostrar Todos os itens" )
                    .insertAfter( input )
                    .button({
                        icons: {
                            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                        },
                        text: false
                    })
                    .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                    .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" )
                    .click(function() {
                        // close if already visible
                        if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                            input.autocomplete( "close" );
                            return;
                        }

                        // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                        input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                        input.focus();
                    });
            }
        });
    })( jQuery );
```

Comment: Could you provide the JavaScript you're using to create the combobox?

Answer (score 0):

Heres the fix my friend pointed. This version of ui.combobox got auto width, and few fixes i found @ web. works on ie also.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
        _create: function() {
            var self = this,
                id = this.element.attr("id"),
                select = this.element,
                theWidth = select.width(),
                selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
                select.hide();
                //fix, doesnt let the element beign too short.
                if(theWidth < 110) {
                    theWidth = 110;
                }
            var input = $('<input id="' + id + '-combo" style="width: ' + theWidth + 'px;">')
                //.insertAfter( select )
                .val( value )
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                        response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                            var text = $( this ).text();
                            if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                                return {
                                    id: this.value,
                                    label: text.replace(
                                        new RegExp(
                                            "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                            $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                            ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                        ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                        }) );
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
                    },
                    change: function( event, ui ) {
                        if ( !ui.item ) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                                valid = false;
                            select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                                if ( this.value.match( matcher ) ) {
                                    this.selected = valid = true;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                            if ( !valid ) {
                                // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                $( this ).val( "" );
                                select.val( "" );
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );
                var span = $('<span style="white-space: nowrap;"></span>')
                .append(input).insertAfter( select );
            input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };

            $("<button id='" + id + "-combo-button'>&nbsp;</button>")
                .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                .attr( "title", "Mostrar Todos os itens" )
                .insertAfter(input)
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" )
                .click(function() {
                    // close if already visible
                    if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                        input.autocomplete( "close" );
                        return;
                    }

                    // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                    input.focus();
                });
        }
    });
})( jQuery );
```